# Is Wolfram Mathematica a suitable tool for quant?

Tags: programming

I have heard many times that such languages as Python, C++, R and Matlab are popular in finance industry. As for the first three it is a clear choice since they are open source and non-proprietary, but using Matlab requires purchasing of license, so my question is can quant (or anyone else doing quantitative tasks) use another proprietary CAS or programming language like Mathematica for example? If not, why just Matlab?

Comment: Very suitable.  
A few quant books even use Mathematica https://www.amazon.com/Option-Valuation-Under-Stochastic-Volatility/dp/0967637201

Comment: There are some (proprietary trading shop) Quant Research departments that used Mathematica almost exclusively.  In the last 10 years other tools have improved more rapidly than Mathematica has.  Those shops no longer use it much.

Comment: To be honest I haven't seen Mathematica in this area for quite some time. Nowadays its mainly R and Python. In my experience Matlab is in decline too.